# Can "guidance" be in line with an "occupation"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I am currently writing statement of purpose for my graduate studies and I find myself struggling with a particular turn of phrase.

I'd like to convey (at this point in my letter in a rather abstract fashion) that I have identified features of the particular style of teaching at a certain institution that I believe to be immensely conducive to the development of certain traits that I find indispensable for my ideal scientific career.

I ended up writing:

> "... that the guidance I stand to receive at [institution] is perfectly aligned with the scientist that I aspire to become."

Broken down to its components, the sentence above assets that a specific type of "guidance" is in line with "the scientist I aspire to become".
I have to admit that I am not perfectly happy with that. I suppose, "guidance" can be in line with traits of a "scientist" but not the "scientist" himself.

So my questions are:

Is the sentence above entirely non-sensical?
and (if not)
Does it sounds natural to a native speaker's ear?

Would I be better off writing something along the lines of:

> "...that the guidance I stand to receive at [institution] will make me best-equipped to become the scientist that I aspire be."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specific concern about this sentence is that the **"guidance" can be in line with traits of a "scientist" but not the "scientist" himself.**

You can easily refer to the traits rather than to the scientist himself by saying "kind of scientist" or "type of scientist".

You go to an institution to receive an **education**: this term covers both the subjects in the curriculum and the philosophy or style of teaching at a particular institution. I think that you can reasonably replace the word **guidance** with **education**.

I prefer the second sentence, but you could replace **make me best equipped** with **best equip me**.

Putting all that together, you would get:

> ...that the education I stand to receive at [institution] will best equip me to become the kind of scientist that I aspire be."